# Distribute Android Project as a JAR

Tags: android, jar, android-resources, android-library

I am planing to distribute a part of my android application as a JAR/Library-Project . I don't want my source code to be visible to the user of my JAR/Library-Project . According to developer doc, it is possible to release an android project as a JAR including resources. But when I tried to start a JAR's activity from my test-client project , it was not able to find a resource file . I also tried to explore the generated R file , but there where no references to layouts and Drawables from the compiled JAR. Is this approach proper, or should I create a Library project for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try Out this:

1. Make your library project a normal project by deselecting IsLibrary flag.
2. Execute your project as Android Application. (It will not show any error)
3. You'll find a .jar file in bin folder along with .apk.
4. Give you .jar who want to use your library.
5. Tell them to just import external jar into build path.

This will work fine with all the resources. Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I tried this.After extracting the Jar file, I found only java classes related to the source code. No trace of any resource files.